# A Non-Platonic Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> On the outside I may sound
>  Like some holy thing.
>  Paint on me a
>   halo,
>  Seven colors I require.
>
> Since I'm wrapped around the void,
>  You may fill me up with
>   air.
>  Let me hold your language
>    while you hold
>   me
>    in the morning.
>
> You recall they called it all
>  But impossible but we
>     all connected
>    three by three,
>     you with me.
>
> I can be a real treat for you
> (That may sound a little bullish,
>     but if that should fail to do,
>    I've a hole inside me too).

---

I'm looking for a specific single word answer, with explanation of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a

> **Torus**

On the outside I may sound
Like some holy thing.

> Holy sounds like "holey" which a torus is (Thanks Deusovi!)

Paint on me a halo,

> Halos are ring-shaped, with some width they'd be torus shaped

Seven colors I require.

> You can color a plane with 4 colors (by the four-color theorem), but a graph on a torus needs 7 colors.

Since I'm wrapped around the void,

> Referring to the fundamental polygon of a torus being equivalent to wrapping around on both edges?

You may fill me up with air.

> You can fill up inner tubes (which are shaped like a torus) with air.

Let me hold your language
  while you hold me
  in the morning.

> Reference to the coffee mug being topologically equivalent to a torus, which people often hold in the morning?

You recall they called it all
But impossible but we
  all connected
  three by three,
  you with me.

> You can't draw a $K_{3,3}$ in a plane (the utilities problem), but you can on a torus?

I can be a real treat for you

> Donuts are shaped like tori.

(That may sound a little bullish,

> Torus sounds like "Taurus" which is the astrological sign of the bull

but if that should fail to do,
  I've a hole inside me too).

> Tori have a hole in themz

Title:

> The torus is not a Platonic solid - for one, it's not convex.

Comment: Gah, beat me to it. For the first two lines, it's either the same as the second-last or something with "holy"/"holey" -- could work either way.

Comment: Also, re the second to last verse, you can remove the question mark... that was precisely what I was going for.